# Action helper inclusion error + getActionController is null

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to write a few action helper but it seems that I am not doing it well.

First of all, in my Bootstrap file, I am doing the following:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/controllers/helpers/My/Helper/', 'My_Helper');
```

In this directory, I have the following tree:

```
My/Helper/
  - Fileupload/
    - Abstract.php
    - Xhr.php
  - Fileupload.php
```

In my Controller, I successfully call the fileupload helper (in the class My_Helper_Fileupload):

```
$res = $this->_helper->fileupload($directory);
```

But in the constructor of this helper, I am trying get another helper (in the class My_Helper_Fileupload_Xhr) iwth:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Fileupload_Xhr');
```

which lead me to the error

> Action Helper by name FileuploadXhr not found

What am I doing wrong? I tried a lot of stuff but I can't figure out what's wrong...

Moreover, after a few test, it seems that in my constructor of the fileupload helper, I am getting NULL when I call the getActionController method. Isn't it supposed to be set automatically?

Comment: You asked two distinct questions here. You gave a lot more details about the paths and loading issue, and I answered that question. It would probably be best to edit your second question out of this one and post it as a full-fledged question of its own, with some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper broker will remove underscores as part of its process of "normalizing" the helper name you give it. It only deals with CamelCased helper names, so your `Fileupload_Xhr` gets converted to `FileuploadXhr`.

The Zend_Loader that ends up being responsible for finding and loading the right PHP file uses underscores to determine when it should add a directory separator.

If you combine these two things, the practical upshot is that you can't have a nested folder structure under any path for the action helper broker. All the helper classes you want to be able to load for any path added with `addPath` must reside directly under the given path, with no intervening subfolders.

The simple solution is to move your helper from `My/Helper/Fileupload/Xhr.php` to `My/Helper/FileuploadXhr.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `My` as your appnamespace - which is what I usually do; `Application` is too long to type - then this is one way to do it.

In Bootstrap:

`Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/controllers/helpers', 'My_Controller_Helper');`

Name your helper class as `My_Controller_Helper_SomeHelper` and store it in the file `application/controllers/helpers/SomeHelper.php`.

Invoke in a controller using:

`$this->_helper->someHelper()`

If your appnamespace is different, the just replace `My_` with your appnamespace.